# How to trigger an event when shield-ui grid cell text box destroyed

Tags: grid, shieldui

As I mentioned in the question title I need to trigger an event as soon as Shield-ui grid editable cell textbox destroyed. Couldnt find a solution in their documentation.Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

**Here is my code so far ...**

```
 $("#allTransGrid").shieldGrid({
                                    dataSource: {
                                        data: datad,
                                        schema: {
                                            fields: {
                                                mbr_id: {path: "mbr_id", type: String},
                                                lon_id: {path: "lon_id", type: String},
                                                center_name: {path: "center_name", type: String},
                                                grp_name: {path: "grp_name", type: String},
                                                mbr_name: {path: "mbr_name", type: String},
                                                lon_amt: {path: "lon_amt", type: Number},
                                                lon_int_amt: {path: "lon_int_amt", type: Number},
                                                loan_total: {path: "loan_total", type: Number},
                                                ind_inst: {path: "ind_inst", type: Number},
                                                today_pay: {path: "today_pay", type: Number, nullable: false},
                                                lon_id_as: {path: "lon_id_as", type: Number}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    sorting: {
                                        multiple: true
                                    },
                                    paging: {
                                        pageSize: 12,
                                        pageLinksCount: 10
                                    },
                                    selection: {
                                        type: "row",
                                        multiple: true,
                                        toggle: false
                                    },
                                    columns: [
                                        {field: "mbr_id", width: "100px", title: "Member ID"},
                                        {field: "lon_id", width: "100px", title: "Loan ID"},
                                        {field: "center_name", title: "Center Name", width: "100px"},
                                        {field: "grp_name", title: "Group Name", width: "70px"},
                                        {field: "mbr_name", title: "Member Name", width: "170px"},
                                        {field: "lon_amt", title: "Loan Amount", width: "100px"},
                                        {field: "lon_int_amt", title: "Interest", width: "100px"},
                                        {field: "loan_total", title: "Total", width: "80px"},
                                        {field: "ind_inst", title: "Installment Amount", width: "120px"},
                                        {field: "today_pay", title: "Today Payment"}
                                    ],
                                    events: {
                                        editorCreating: function (e) {
                                            if (e.field == "ind_inst") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false, max: 1000};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "loan_total") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false, max: 500000};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "lon_int_amt") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false, max: 100000};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "lon_amt") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false, max: 100000};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "mbr_name") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "grp_name") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "center_name") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "lon_id") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "mbr_id") {
                                                e.options = {enabled: false};
                                            }
                                            if (e.field == "today_pay") {
                                                e.options = {max: 10000};
                                            }
                                        },
                                        detailCreated: function (e) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: "PaymentCatcherGroupBy",
                                                cache: false,
                                                dataType: 'JSON',
                                                data: {loan_id: e.item.lon_id_as, c_id: center_id},
                                                success: function (data) {
                                                    $("<div/>")
                                                            .appendTo(e.detailCell)
                                                            .shieldGrid({
                                                                dataSource: {data: data},
                                                                sorting: {
                                                                    multiple: true
                                                                },
                                                                paging: {
                                                                    pageSize: 5
                                                                },
                                                                columns: [
                                                                    {field: "installment_num", title: "Week", editable: false},
                                                                    {field: "installmentAmount", title: "Installment Amount", editable: false},
                                                                    {field: "paidAmount", title: "Paid Amount", editable: false},
                                                                    {field: "dueDate", title: "Date Paid", type: Date, editable: false}
                                                                ], editing: {enabled: false}
                                                            });
                                                }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                    alert('error');
                                                }
                                            });

                                        },
                                        command: function (e) {
//selectionChanged doesnt work here....
                                            if (e.commandName == "selectionChanged") {
                                                var toBeSelected = e.toBeSelected;
                                                console.log(toBeSelected);
                                                //   e.cancel = true;
                                            }

                                        }
                                    },
                                    editing: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        event: "doubleclick",
                                        type: "cell"
                                    },
                                    scrolling: true,
                                    height: 600
                                });
```

**After focus lost of the textbox I need to trigger an event :**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no destroy event, associated with any of the editors in the control, when in edit mode. 
One option, depending on the final goal that you have would be to subscribe to the command event:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/events/command
which should be triggered on save, after an edit. 
If that is not an option, please supply some additional information on what is the exact end result that you are after.

Comment: Actually I need to trigger an event right after I change the cell value. Not on cell clicked. That is way I asked about an event after  destroying the textbox inside the cell. `selectionChanged` event does not usefull in this case.

Comment: For this purpose, you may want to create a custom editor, and handle all tracking/notification by subscribing to the client events of the input control.
This is demonstrated below:
http://jsbin.com/yujujoteco/edit?html,output

Comment: Sorry ! that is not what I wanted.. And also it comes with `TypeError: $(...).swidget(...) is null` Error , once I click another cell.

Comment: I have attached a pic of what I really expected if still there is a confusion with my question.

Comment: In this case, the logic stays similar - in the sample which I attached, you need to add an onchange event for the input - and update the values there. 
I have prepared another jsBin, which handles the logic completely:
http://jsbin.com/layesa/3/edit?html,output